# What do the difficulty settings do?

Tags: pc, tomb-raider-anniversary

What do the difficulty settings in *Tomb Raider: Anniversary* do? Will setting the difficulty to easy just remove boss/enemy health, or will it also modify other aspects of the game?

(I like the gameplay a lot, but these boss battles are awful.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty settings change how hard the enemies will hit you and also how many times you will have to hit the enemy before they die.

It does not remove the bosses from the game. And it doesn't change any of the puzzles either.

It's been answered here:

http://uk.gamespot.com/tombraider10thanniversaryedition/forum/messages/platform/ps2?topic_id=m-1-42458488&pid=934025

Comment: Does it change the damage received from environmental hazards such as the rotating flame traps?